# DomDocument remove attribute

Tags: php, dom, attributes

Ok, I have just spent the whole day playing with DomDocument and creating some cool things. The only thing I cannot figure out is how I can delete an attribute of a DomElement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`removeAttribute`

Comment: Wow, you have no idea how many hours i have spent scouring the php DOM manual for that method. I feel so dumb but thanks for pointing it out.